# How triggers are called when we have two triggers?

Tags: sql-server, trigger

In a table I have two triggers. When it is called for the first time the first trigger does not fires while the second trigger's got fired.  On the next call both first and second trigger action take place. So in my case when calling the trigger first time the first trigger should be executed then the second one. Any suggestions?

Comment: You should show both trigger definitions and the table you try to modify.  Without that we can't even guess.

Answer (score 4):

If I am understanding your question correctly, you are looking for the `sp_settriggerorder` system stored procedure (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186762.aspx). Through the used of this stored proc you can set whether a trigger fires first or last (or undefined, and any trigger in between first and last has no guaranteed order).

(Note: this only applies to AFTER triggers, and cannot be used with INSTEAD OF triggers)

Comment: In my case not like that using sp_settriggerorder because once trigger  called for first time the first trigger holds and second trigger called then again calling both executed. while calling first itself i need first trigger to be called

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding what you're trying to accomplish.  Can you reword?